# Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence in Spring ROO

Tags: spring-roo

Xello, everyone!

Pls could anyone help with new Spring ROO (1.2.1.RELEASE [rev 6eae723]) - i originally used Spring-roo-1.2.0.M1. Now i have strange error, and no stacktrace (btw, where are the logs for Spring Roo? felix.log.level is set to 4):

```
Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\i18n\application.properties
Updated SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\i18n\application.properties
Undo manage SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\i18n\application.properties
Undo create SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\i18n\application.properties
Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

It halts and does nothing after that. On 1.20 everything was OK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Mac? I had the same error on Mac and resolved it by setting file.encoding in ROO_OPTS.

```
$ ROO_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 roo.sh
```

Comment: Good answer! I will accept it. I think, on my Windows machine this also should help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use comments for tables with UTF-8, after clearing DB , roo work without errors ;)